# Cloud Foundry account id

Tags: cloud-foundry, mindsphere

When I want to use Cloud Foundry API from outside MindSphere environment, it is needed to get an access token by calling this endpoint:
https://"your account id".piam.eu1.mindsphere.io/oauth/token

My question is:
What "your account id" means here, and where can I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is usually your tenant ID, which means you should get that when signing the contract with Siemens.

Comment: This not works with my tenant id. I could not get any response calling that.

Comment: I did have a "\n" character at the end of my Authorization param. I think it should send a response with error instead of not respond. Thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome, even if it was not really fixing your issue :)